# How do I send UDP packets to the UDP server I have created in Python (3.7.3)?

Tags: python, server, udp, packet

Please let me begin saying I'm new to Python (first year CS student) and this is the first programming language I am learning.

I have an assignment which has 2 parts; Client and Server

On the server side I am trying to:

1) create a server that constantly awaits UDP messages and waits for two distinct UDP messages (string1 and string2)

2) It then concatenates the strings of the 2 packets as string3 and sends it to the client in a single UDP Packet and starts again.

e.g. server receives string1 and string2 as pinea and pples, constructs pineapples as string3 and sends string3 to the client

On the client side I am required to write some code which:
1) prompts the client for a string upon start up#

2) splits that string in to 2 (n/2 if n is even and 
(n+1)/2 and (n-1)/2 if n is odd)

3) awaits string from the server in a separate UDP packet

4) checks if string from server = concatenation of the two split strings

5) displays the result of the final answer

e.g. user enters string as pineapples, client sends string1 and string2 as pinea and pples; then receives string3 from server as pineapples and checks that string3==string1+string2.

I am trying to figure out why after setting up my server I am unable to send the packets to and from the server.

I am currently using Python IDLE 3.7.3, I've watched quite a few videos and read some of the other stack overflow forums but have been unable to determine the problem, as mentioned previously I am a beginner and would greatly appreciate any help

Here is my code:

for the server I have:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
address = ("127.0.0.1", 5002)
sock.bind (address)

while True:
    data,addr= sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print (data)
    print (addr)

sock.listen(5)
```

my client code is as follows:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s=str(input("Please input a word: "))
string1 = s[:len(s)//2]
string2 = s[:len(s)//2:] 
message1= string1.encode()
message2= string2.encode()
sock.sendto(message1+message1,("127.0.0.1",5002))
received= sock.recv(1024)
received==string1+string2

while True:
    print (message1, message2)
    print (received)
```

I am currently receiving the error message 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' when I attempt to run my client code.

Thank you very much (this is also my first time using Stack Overflow so please let me know if I may have done anything inappropriate in my post so I can rectify)

Comment: `received==` ?....the last while loop is only printing forever?

Comment: Please don't double space every code line, or add an extra indent to all.  If you think that the editor/IDE has any affect on how the code runs, run it directly with Python from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be strangely structured, `while` loops out of sequence/doing nonsensical things, etc...

I've tidied up/rewritten your code such that works for me.  I'm using context managers in order that the sockets get cleaned up nicely.  For the server, something like:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5002))

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(8192)
        print(data, addr)
        sock.sendto(b"hi from server", addr)
```

and the client:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5002))

    sock.send(b"hi from client")
    print(sock.recvfrom(8192))
```

UDP is obviously "connection-less" but calling `connect` allows name resolution to be performed once rather than every time you `send`.  I've also hard coded the messages that are sent for simplicity.

When debugging it helps to remove as much complexity as possible, in this case reading input seems to have little relevance to network code.

I'd also suggest using `socket.getaddrinfo` so your code can more easily work with IPv6, but that's a seperate issue.

Comment: Many thanks for this, Sam. I've run the client code and received the following error message: 

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I've had a look online and some people have said this is just because the connection has timed out … am I missing something? do I not need sock.listen() at the end of my server code?

Thanks!

Comment: `listen` is mostly for TCP sockets, and hence doesn't apply to UDP.  UDP doesn't use "connections", so they can't time out.  I'd guess some sort of firewall interaction.. also, you are running these on the same computer aren't you?  how long does it take before you get the error.  I also haven't touched a Windows computer for a few years, so can't help much there